# Remove colon from keyword in C++ file?

Tags: vimrc, filetype, filetype-c++

`:` is set as keyword (`set iskeyword`) for C++ source file by default, is there a way to just disable that in my .vimrc file instead of doing `set iskeyword-=:` every time? It seems the plug-in set the keyword is loaded after loading .vimrc file.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could put

```
setlocal iskeyword-=:
```

inside `~/.vim/after/ftplugin/cpp.vim`

Loads automatically when you open files where the `filetype` is `cpp`. If it doesn't work, try setting `filetype plugin on`.

**Update**:

Or you could do

```
autocmd FileType cpp :setlocal iskeyword-=:
```

In your `.vimrc`, but I recommend you put it in a ftplugin - it keeps your `.vimrc` clutter-free.

Comment: It's better to put it inside `~/.vim/after/ftplugin/cpp.vim` and also use: `setlocal` instead of `set`: `setlocal iskeyword-=:`

Comment: That's true. I forgot about `/after` and kinda just copied the command from Q. Updated answer to reflect this, thanks.